# How to work with Restful web service using jersey.Iam new to this Topic

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Please suggest spring restful web service ..I have one doubt if iam having web service in one dynamic web project how can i get the value in client side(or)
For Example:
client side(Dynamic web project) iam giving two data 2 and 3 how to send this data to server side(onather Dynamic web project) for addition purpose is that possible.how server get data from client which is in another project.suggest some codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have any number of projects in single eclipse workspace working individually say WSClient (WS Client code) and WSServer (WS developed and deployed using this) two separate projects.

Here is the sample SpringController using Spring MVC to develop RESTful service:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SpringRestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = { "/testApplication" }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public String getServerInfo() {
        System.out.println("I got hit");
        String message = "Hit the end point";
        return message;
    }
}
```

Once you deployed the above service then you can consume this using even Browser. Once done that then use Service Client to consume the same.

Comment: if we run restful how will be output

Comment: I would recommend to use Spring MVC to develop RESTful services because that is very-2 simple to learn. You can also consume the services using any HTTP client or specific APIs like Jersey, CXF few to name.

Comment: Bro How will consumer consume this is there any code please send bro or suggest any site

Comment: Shared Jersey client code by @bpetlur, use this to access the service. You need to use the correct resource URI instead of http://localhost:8080/testApplication as per your context i.e. <host>:<port>/<appContext>/<URI>

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks you can use to consume the REST web-service, one of them i had used is **Jersey** which is implemented based on the **JAX-RS specification**.

Below is the sample Code of Jersey client consuming REST Web-service

REST WS Project

```
//Person pojo
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)      
public class Person implements Serializable  {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8979562848777300129L;

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email

   //setter and getter methods  
}

//REST WS controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class SBUserController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") 
public Person fetchProfile() {

//implement service layer and dao layer to fetch user profile from DB
//testing purpose i am creating one person and returning back
    Person person  = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("John");
    person.setLastName("Terry");
    person.setEmail("john@gmail.com");

    return person;
}
}
```

//Client Side

```
   Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/user/profile");

ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (clientResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
        //You need to have the same Person bean class in client project also
          Person person = clientResponse.getEntity(Person.class));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Bro tis very helpfull

Comment: Please do upvote or accept it as answered if its helpful. Let me know for any further help.

Comment: Sorry bro simply passing the url we can access another dynamic web project if both are deployed in tomcat srver

Comment: Yes you can consume the REST WS using the URL. Even your client and server application are deployed in different server also, you can access with proper host name, App context name and port number.

If you are thinking of application security, we have authentication and authorization implementation to restrict the access of the application.

Comment: Like this can we call WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/testApplication");

Comment: Data exchange between Client (Consumer) and REST WS (Producer) happens using JSON objects. Using Jackson library at Client side you can unmarshal the response from REST WS. Please find the updated answer for sample code how client and REST interact.

Comment: Thanks for your replay           # bpetlur              Person person = clientResponse.getEntity(Person.class));
If i gave like this in client side .its throwing  error.     If client is in one dynamic project and client is in another dynamic project how can we import the class of server in client because they are in dynamic web project is there any way to do.I cant understand that logic please explain how client gets webservice (Person Class) if it is in different Dynamicweb project.

Comment: You should have the same Entity class in your client project as well.

Comment: That means we need to create same class in our project

Comment: Yes, The same class with same field names and types.

Comment: Hoo k bro is there any annotation to link this pojo class are it will done automatically

Comment: Its difficult for me to understand bro very tough to get through is there any websit i need to see full coding then after onl i can understand